# Is there a good IDE for React Native on Windows?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, ide

I have just started working with React Native and was hoping there was an equivalent IDE like Nuclide or Deco for the Windows OS. I have been working in Notepad++ but am a little dissatisfied because of no autocomplete of my code or color coordinated methods.

Comment: There are any number of IDEs, but StackOverflow is more about how to fix a problem than who thinks whether x or y is best.

Comment: My problem is finding a proficient IDE because I cannot seem to find a good one, and thus I am in need of assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try webstorm (since you dont specify if you want a free IDE)

Comment: This is perfect! It supports React (along with JS and Flow). Thank you

Comment: Does anybody have a good free IDE they use?

Answer (score 2):

I am currently using Atom with Nuclide on Windows 10 and after some tweaking it is working great. I highly recommend it if you want to stick with Windows.

https://nuclide.io/docs/editor/setup/#windows